# Is there a word/phrase for when you hate a nickname but if one person says it you secretly like it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Say you hate being called a specific nickname or pet name, but there’s one person who calls you it and you secretly like it? I’ve tried finding a word, but I don’t know if there is one. Maybe there’s a phrase?

Comment: Why would there be a word for this? There is a sentence such as the one you used.

Comment: Lambie seems to have said it all… Either way, in my view word, phrase or expression requests should be promoted to their own specialised community, perhaps named 'Vocabulary.'

Answer (score 0):

One expression is to have a **soft spot** for someone. [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/soft+spot) has

> **a soft spot**
> A particular fondness or affection for someone or something, often for reasons that [are] hard to understand or articulate.

So you could say:

> I hate being called diddykins but secretly like it when X calls me that. I have a soft spot for her/him.